# Flutter - provider: ^6.0.1, type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Address' in type cast

Tags: flutter, provider

Please guide me how to solve this error.

below is the part of the log

The following _CastError was thrown building MainScreen(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<AppData?>], state: _MainScreenState#8d426):
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Address' in type cast

Below are the classes and code:

```
class Address {
  String placeFormattedAddress;
  String placeName;
  String placeId;
  double latitude;
  double longitude;

  Address({
    this.placeFormattedAddress="Google Building 40, 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
    this.placeName="Google Building 40",
    this.placeId="ChIJj38IfwK6j4ARNcyPDnEGa9g",
    this.latitude=37.4237151802915,
    this.longitude= -122.0825955197085
  });
}

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:rider_app_kotlin/Models/address.dart';

class AppData extends ChangeNotifier {
  late Address pickUpLocation;

  void updatePickUpLocationAddress(Address pickUpAddress){
    pickUpLocation = pickUpAddress;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this is related to sound null safety. please help.

below is the code related to updatePickupLocationAddress;

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:rider_app_kotlin/Assistants/request_assistant.dart';
import 'package:rider_app_kotlin/DataHandler/app_data.dart';
import 'package:rider_app_kotlin/Models/address.dart';
import 'package:rider_app_kotlin/config_maps.dart';

class Assistant {
  static Future<String> searchCoordinateAddress(Position position, context) async {
    String placeAddress = "";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
        "${position.latitude},${position.longitude}&key=$mapKey";

    var  response = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(url);

    if(response != "Failed."){
      placeAddress = response["results"][0]["formatted_address"];  

      Address userPickUpAddress = new Address();
      userPickUpAddress.latitude  = position.latitude; 
      userPickUpAddress.longitude = position.longitude;
      userPickUpAddress.placeName = placeAddress;

      Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
          .updatePickUpLocationAddress(userPickUpAddress);

    }
    return placeAddress;
  }
}
```

additional information: the data on the AppData class should be display in the MainScreen class using 'provider' package in the code below;

```
Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
       children: [
          Text(
            Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickUpLocation != null
            ? Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickUpLocation.placeName
            :"Add Home", 
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 4,),
          Text("Home address", style:TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15),)
       ],
     ),
```

EDIT: 25JAN2022;
Issue Still appear in the start of application.

while troubleshooting, I tried to remove the 'Provider.of(context).pickUpLocation != null
? Provider.of(context).pickUpLocation.placeName
:' in MainScreen and retain only this "Add Home", then the app was reloaded(Hot Reload) successfully without the error stated(in the subject), and of course the address was not displayed in the mainscreen.

I tried again to place the Provider.of(context).pickUpLocation != null
? Provider.of(context).pickUpLocation.placeName
: "Add Home" and the app was reloaded(Hot Reload) succesfully without error and the address was displayed in the mainsreen - as intended.

I tried to start the app from the beginning (not Hot Reload), then I encountered again the Error. Please suggest what to check here. Thank you.

Comment: AppData and Address class are separate dart file.

Comment: where from you call the `updatePickUpLocationAddress ` function, can you share this part code

Comment: Where and how you are using `updatePickUpLocationAddress`?

Comment: I already updated the details, please check above. thank you.

Comment: still have the issue. please check my latest update.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

---

```
  class Address {
      var placeFormattedAddress;
      var placeName;
      var placeId;
      var latitude;
      var longitude;
    
      Address({
        this.placeFormattedAddress="Google Building 40, 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
        this.placeName="Google Building 40",
        this.placeId="ChIJj38IfwK6j4ARNcyPDnEGa9g",
        this.latitude=37.4237151802915,
        this.longitude= -122.0825955197085
      });
    }
    
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:rider_app_kotlin/Models/address.dart';
    
    class AppData extends ChangeNotifier {
      late Address pickUpLocation;
    
      void updatePickUpLocationAddress(Address pickUpAddress){
        pickUpLocation = pickUpAddress;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

Comment: still have the same issue after using 'var'.

Comment: if(response != "Failed.") change this to "Failed"

Comment: I cannot change it to "Failed" because I have another class which return exactly "Failed." string.

Comment: it seems problem is in the response , please recheck your response

Comment: I still have the same issue. please see my latest edit, about the issue. Sorry, I don't know where to check this issue. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dynamic

```
class Address {
  dynamic placeFormattedAddress;
  dynamic PlaceName;
  dynamic PlaceId;
  dynamic latitude;
  dynamic longitude;

  Address({
    this.placeFormattedAddress="Google Building 40, 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, 
     Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
    this.placeName="Google Building 40",
    this.placeId="ChIJj38IfwK6j4ARNcyPDnEGa9g",
    this.latitude=37.4237151802915,
    this.longitude= -122.0825955197085
  });
}
```

Comment: I already tried to use the dynamic, but still have the same error.